# How to play sound when timer reaches zero?

Tags: c++, winapi, timer, while-loop

I am trying to make a timer and have it play a sound at the end. I have made the timer and it works fine but the sound won't play. This is what I have so far:

```
int main() {
    //cout << "This is a timer. It is still in the making but it the seconds work properly." << endl;
    //Sleep(7000);
    //system("CLS");

    int input;

    cout << "Enter a time: ";
    cin >> input;
    cout << endl << "Begin." << endl;
    system("CLS");

    while (input != 0) {
        input--;
        cout << input << " seconds" << endl;
        Sleep(200);
        system("CLS");

        if (input == 0) {
            PlaySound(TEXT("C:\\Users\\iD Student\\Downloads\\Never_Gonna_Hit_Those_Notes.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You 're playing the sound in async mode. I guess the main terminates before the sound starts playing. Try to remove `SND_ASYNC`.

Comment: Thank you Dim! Removing 'SND_ASYNC' fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the `SND_ASYNC` flag is the culprit, you need to remove it.

I would also suggest you restructure your code to move the `PlaySound()` outside of the loop.  There is no point in checking `input` for 0 multiple times in the loop.  The code after the loop will be called when the loop ends:

```
const char* plural[] = {"", "s"};

int main()
{
    int input;

    cout << "Enter # of seconds: ";
    cin >> input;

    system("CLS");
    cout << "Begin." << endl;

    while (input > 0)
    {
        system("CLS");
        cout << input << " second" << plural[input != 1] << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
        --input;
    }

    system("CLS");
    cout << "Done." << endl;

    PlaySound(TEXT("C:\\Users\\iD Student\\Downloads\\Never_Gonna_Hit_Those_Notes.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of SND_ASYNC at the end:

```
int main()
{
    int input;

    cout << "Enter a time: ";
    cin >> input;
    cout << endl << "Begin." << endl;
    system("CLS");

    while (input != 0) {
        input--;
        cout << input << " seconds" << endl;
        Sleep(200);
        system("CLS");

        if (input == 0) {
            PlaySound(TEXT("C:\\Users\\iD Student\\Downloads\\Never_Gonna_Hit_Those_Notes.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
        }
    }
}
```